# How to get the route params and pass it as props for named views?

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3

My application have navbar with back button. The navbarTop is a named views, so I can have different navbar for each route, and the navbar needs props backRoute.

I define the back route like this:

```js
{
  path: '/:id',
  name: 'orders detail',
  components: {
    default: OrderDetail,
    navbarTop: Navbar,
  },
  props: {
    navbarTop: {
      backRoute: { name: 'orders' },
      title: 'Order Detail',
    },
    default: true,
  },
},
{
  path: '/:id/request-cancel',
  name: 'orders request cancel',
  components: {
    default: OrderRequestCancel,
    navbarTop: Navbar,
  },
  props: {
    navbarTop: {
      backRoute: { name: 'orders', params: {id: ???} }, // how to get the id here?
      title: 'Request Cancel',
    },
    default: true,
  },
},
```

Is it possible to get the id in route and pass it as prop to the component?
The NavbarTop is named view and is used in many routes, so I can't update the back route from OrderRequestCancel component.

Comment: Have you tried the [function mode](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode)?

Comment: @YomS. Thank you. Didn't know we can use this.
Do you want to put this as anwer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [Function Mode](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode)

```js
props: {
  navbarTop: route => ({
    backRoute: { name: 'order detail', params: { id: route.params.id } },
    title: 'Request Cancel',
  }),
  default: true,
},
```

Thank you @Yom S. for the hint.